# Openshift: unable to create deployer pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

We are observing a very weird behavior with our openshift cluster. As soon as the DeploymentConfig is created, the replication controller fails with  message `unable to create deployer pod`

Describing the rc does not give any other useful information

```
$ oc describe rc example-1

Name:         example-1
Namespace:    example-test
Selector:     app=hello-openshift,deployment=example-1,deploymentconfig=example
Labels:       openshift.io/deployment-config.name=example
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas: 3
              openshift.io/deployment-config.latest-version: 1
              openshift.io/deployment-config.name: example
              openshift.io/deployment.phase: Failed
              openshift.io/deployment.replicas: 0
              openshift.io/deployment.status-reason: unable to create deployer pod
              openshift.io/encoded-deployment-config:
                {"kind":"DeploymentConfig","apiVersion":"apps.openshift.io/v1","metadata":{"name":"example","namespace":"example-test","selfLink":"/apis/a...
Replicas:     0 current / 0 desired
Pods Status:  0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:       app=hello-openshift
                deployment=example-1
                deploymentconfig=example
  Annotations:  openshift.io/deployment-config.latest-version: 1
                openshift.io/deployment-config.name: example
                openshift.io/deployment.name: example-1
  Containers:
   hello-openshift:
    Image:        openshift/hello-openshift
    Port:         8080/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:           <none>
```

Even events only shows just the timeout message

```
$ oc get events

8m7s        Normal    DeploymentCreated   deploymentconfig/example             Created new replication controller "example-1" for version 1
8m7s        Warning   RolloutTimeout      deploymentconfig/example             Rollout for "example-test/example-1" failed to create deployer pod (timeoutSeconds: 600s)
```

Here is the describe output of deployment config

```
$oc describe dc/example
Name:           example
Namespace:      example-test
Created:        5 hours ago
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:    <none>
Latest Version: 1
Selector:       app=hello-openshift
Replicas:       4
Triggers:       Config
Strategy:       Rolling
Template:
Pod Template:
  Labels:       app=hello-openshift
  Containers:
   hello-openshift:
    Image:              openshift/hello-openshift
    Port:               8080/TCP
    Host Port:          0/TCP
    Environment:        <none>
    Mounts:             <none>
  Volumes:              <none>

Deployment #1 (latest):
        Name:           example-1
        Created:        5 hours ago
        Status:         Failed
        Replicas:       0 current / 0 desired
        Selector:       app=hello-openshift,deployment=example-1,deploymentconfig=example
        Labels:         openshift.io/deployment-config.name=example
        Pods Status:    0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed

Events: <none>
```

Does anyone have a pointer to debug the issue here?

Comment: Which openshift version are you using?

Comment: What is the state of the deployer Pod for this time? Please also provide the output for `oc get pods`

Comment: I am using openshift version 4.3. Deployer pod did not get created. `oc get pods` doesn't return anything since there is no pod created

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, similar errors could be shown when the "deployer" Pod stays in "ContainerCreating" or similar. Can you add the output for `oc describe dc`? Typically, more information on why the Pod was unable to be created are shown there.

Comment: since the describe output is too long to add as a comment, I have edited the op and updated it over there

Comment: `Events: <none>`. Hmm, no events are shown, they may have expired. Can you rollout the deployment again using `oc rollout latest dc/example` and then check the Events in the DeploymentConfig again? Typically, this shows the root cause.

Comment: I eventually ended up fixing the issue by restart controller-manager pods